# Adding directive makes controller undefined in angular js code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

Here is my angular js app with html code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        angular.module("demo", []).controller('DemoController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.user = {
                dateOfBirth: new Date(1970, 0, 1)
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoController">
        Date Of Birth:
        <my-datepicker type="text" ng-model="user.dateOfBirth" />
        <br />
        Current user's date of birth: <span id="dateOfBirthDisplay">{{user.dateOfBirth}}</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine.But the moment i add a directive to it, it shows error

```
Error: Argument 'DemoController' is not a function, got undefined
```

Here is the full code with directive

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        angular.module("demo", []).controller('DemoController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.user = {
                dateOfBirth: new Date(1970, 0, 1)
            }
        });
        angular.module("demo", []).directive('myDatepicker', function ($parse) {
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                replace: true,
                transclude: false,
                compile: function (element, attrs) {
                    var modelAccessor = $parse(attrs.ngModel);

                    var html = "<input type='text' id='" + attrs.id + "' >" +
            "</input>";

                    var newElem = $(html);
                    element.replaceWith(newElem);

                    return function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {

                        var processChange = function () {
                            var date = new Date(element.datepicker("getDate"));

                            scope.$apply(function (scope) {
                                // Change bound variable
                                modelAccessor.assign(scope, date);
                            });
                        };

                        element.datepicker({
                            inline: true,
                            onClose: processChange,
                            onSelect: processChange
                        });

                        scope.$watch(modelAccessor, function (val) {
                            var date = new Date(val);
                            element.datepicker("setDate", date);
                        });

                    };

                }
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoController">
        Date Of Birth:
        <my-datepicker type="text" ng-model="user.dateOfBirth" />
        <br />
        Current user's date of birth: <span id="dateOfBirthDisplay">{{user.dateOfBirth}}</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i'm following the tutorial from this link http://henriquat.re/directives/advanced-directives-combining-angular-with-existing-components-and-jquery/angularAndJquery.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are defining the `demo` module twice. By passing a second argument to the [`angular.module` method](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.module), you create a new module. Don't pass the second argument to return a reference to an existing module:

```
// Create a module
angular.module("demo", []).controller('DemoController', function ($scope) {
    // ...
});
// Get reference to module
angular.module("demo").directive('myDatepicker', function ($parse) {
    //              ^ Only one argument
});
```

Note that the `controller` method returns the module to allow chaining, and the `module` method also obviously returns the module, so you also have two other options:

Chaining:

```
angular.module("demo", []).controller('DemoController', function ($scope) {
    // ...
}).directive('myDatepicker', function ($parse) {
    // ...
});
```

Storing reference to module:

```
var demo = angular.module("demo", []);
demo.controller('DemoController', function ($scope) {
    // ...
});
demo.directive('myDatepicker', function ($parse) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Now after modifying the code it gives me error   " TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'datepicker' "

Comment: @iBlue - That looks like an issue with your date picker plugin. Are you including the appropriate script? (I can't see a jQuery UI include in your code for example)

Comment: +1 as you need to be careful to NOT redefine the module. There is a bit of discussion here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1779